# Android: List View Selected item -1

Tags: android

Im getting a -1 value when i try to get the selected item position on my listview that is already populated.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener
(
   new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
   {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view,int arg2, long arg3)
       {
          int selectedPosition = adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition();
          ShowAlert(String.valueOf(selectedPosition));
       }
   }
);
```

To fill my list view i use the following code:

```
SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(
          this, 
          mylist, 
          R.layout.listviewtest,
          new String[] {"test1", "test2", "test3"}, 
          new int[] {R.id.TextView_websitename, R.id.TextView_keywords, R.id.TextView_backlink});
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards.

Jose.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That means there is no row selected. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition%28%29) states that `getSelectedItemPosition()` returns:

> int Position (starting at 0), or
>   INVALID_POSITION if there is nothing
>   selected.

And `INVALID_POSITION` is [`-1`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#INVALID_POSITION).

Note that you are calling `getSelectedItemPosition()` from an `OnClickListener`. Click and selection are not necessarily related. Selection comes from using the D-pad or trackball to navigate the list contents. If the user taps on the screen (or clicks in the emulator), there will be no selection anymore, but there will still be a click event.

The `arg2` value you show is the position of the clicked-upon item in the list.

Comment: Incredible answer, it was very very useful, thanks a lot.

Regards.
Jose.